# UIWebView crash: OpenGLES - glTexImage2D

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiwebview, webgl

I have a `UIWebView` based iOS application which has recently started crashing quite a lot. I strongly believe the crash is caused by something that has changed in the web content (worst-case, but maybe most likely, scenario is it's a 3rd party banner ad), since the crash reports started to come in for all version of my iOS app on the same day, suddenly going from 0 to several hundred crashes.

Here is the crash stack trace on iOS9:

```
Thread : Crashed: WebThread
0  libmetal_timestamp.dylib       0x18cf2df08 (Missing)
1  libmetal_timestamp.dylib       0x18cf2eec4 (Missing)
2  libmetal_timestamp.dylib       0x18cf335ac (Missing)
3  MobileCoreServices             0x185c941a8 (Missing)
4  MobileCoreServices             0x185bf3428 (Missing)
5  OpenGLES                       0x185ccea9c glTexImage2D + 108
6  WebCore                        0x1946e3da8 WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::texImage2D(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*) + 60
7  WebCore                        0x194ffb37c WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::texImage2DBase(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*, int&) + 160
8  WebCore                        0x194ffbb84 WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::texImage2D(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, JSC::ArrayBufferView*, int&) + 784
9  WebCore                        0x194b80ba4 WebCore::jsWebGLRenderingContextBasePrototypeFunctionTexImage2D(JSC::ExecState*) + 2880
10 JavaScriptCore                 0x1842422f0 llint_entry + 25056
11 JavaScriptCore                 0x184241d10 llint_entry + 23552
12 JavaScriptCore                 0x184241d10 llint_entry + 23552
13 JavaScriptCore                 0x184241d10 llint_entry + 23552
14 JavaScriptCore                 0x18423bef8 vmEntryToJavaScript + 312
15 JavaScriptCore                 0x184168c48 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 180
16 JavaScriptCore                 0x183e02108 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 400
17 JavaScriptCore                 0x183eb41bc JSC::boundFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 512
18 JavaScriptCore                 0x18423c080 vmEntryToNative + 320
19 JavaScriptCore                 0x183e0214c JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 468
20 JavaScriptCore                 0x183f117dc JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 80
21 WebCore                        0x1943b8ecc WebCore::JSCallbackData::invokeCallback(JSC::JSValue, JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer&, bool*) + 580
22 WebCore                        0x194a60434 WebCore::JSRequestAnimationFrameCallback::handleEvent(double) + 196
23 WebCore                        0x194dd634c WebCore::ScriptedAnimationController::serviceScriptedAnimations(double) + 424
24 WebCore                        0x194575c48 WebCore::DisplayRefreshMonitor::displayDidRefresh() + 428
25 QuartzCore                     0x187567840 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 40
26 QuartzCore                     0x1875676f4 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 424
27 IOKit                          0x183a262f8 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18272e840 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
29 CoreFoundation                 0x182744c7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
30 CoreFoundation                 0x1827443b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18274210c __CFRunLoopRun + 1800
32 CoreFoundation                 0x182670ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
33 WebCore                        0x19425a54c RunWebThread(void*) + 456
34 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x197c83b28 _pthread_body + 156
35 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x197c83a8c _pthread_body + 154
36 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x197c81028 thread_start + 4
```

On iOS8 it crashes with a slightly different but very very similar stack trace. The iOS8 and iOS9 crashes started at the same time so it's undoubtedly the same thing.

Given the `OpenGLES` references in the crash report I suspect it has something to do with DOM rendering involving the hardware. Has anyone else developed a hybrid web app and seen these crashes? Any specific CSS transforms/transitions that caused the app to crash this way?

Also, there's a reference to `WebGLRenderingContextBase`, does that mean that it must be caused by actual `WebGL` on the web page or could it still originate just form non-3D CSS styles?

Comment: I believe webkit uses OpenGL textures for image compositing... looks like a webkit bug. Probably somewhere in here: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/html/canvas/WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp

Comment: @wcochran Thanks! It seems it's on line 3030 there. Do you have any idea about what on the web page could cause this? Crashlytics says the app is never in focus when it happens (which is good of course) but I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I'm 99% sure it's WebGL. I worked on WebGL in WebKit and I don't believe any non WebGL code uses `WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase`  As for what causes it I have no idea. Try to capture the URL of your UIWebView in your crash report

Comment: @gman Ok thanks! I don't have any WebGL in my own code but I've sometimes seen 3D ads from the ad provider. I'll contact them to see if they started to provide a new ad the day the crashes started to occur...